# Changing Sphinx maximum query length

Tags: php, sphinx

I'm using Sphinx 2.0.4 with PHP with the extended match mode enabled. When I try to use the Sphinx query language, I can only get results if I use 10 words or less. For example, if I searched for something like `a | b` it will work just fine, but if I search for `a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k` it will always return no results, even if there are matches. Anyone know of a setting to increase this limit? I poked around in the config file but the changes I made didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Do you use the php API and did you check the sphinx log? I have no trouble searching with 11+ words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that is the issue? I've used queries much longer than that (eg having over 100 or'ed keywords), that work just fine.

In fact just tried...

```
select * from sample8 where match('one | two | three | four | five | six | seven | eight | nine | ten | eleven | twelve');
<SNIP>
20 rows in set (0.28 sec)

select * from sample8 where match('a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k');
<SNIP>
20 rows in set (1.14 sec)
```

Suggest posting an actual REAL query tha fails, rather than a fake one.

Comment: You were right, it was a completely unrelated issue and the 10 word thing was a coincidence. Thanks for helping me narrow it down!

Answer (score 0):

If you use not SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED/SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2 match mode, only 10 keywords from query used.  Extended2 is default mode and supports query language, not only boolean operators like SPH_MATCH_BOOLEAN mode.

Andrew Aksyonoff here said http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=1743 about the limits.

For more info about match modes see  http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#matching-modes